# Windows 7 Explorer menu bar, my new nightmare!

Tags: windows-7

I've tried anything you can think of to hide the windows 7 explorer's menu bar but it didn't work. something is wrong with mine, help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `View`

Uncheck "Always show menus"

`Apply` -> `OK`

[image]